# C++: do I need / can I use exception handling when doing sanity-checks in constructor>?

Tags: c++, exception

I'm building a project for school and I thought I'd like to slip in some exception handling (a topic we spoke about in class).

I've been reading into them to see where and how I can use them, so far I think I can follow the philosophy, but just to check if I'm right I thought I'd post this question.

Is it useful to use exception handling in an object's constructor to prevent it's data members from taking illegal values (e.g. make sure a mass isn't negative etc)?

What about in functions that modify the object's datamembers (e.g. a function that modifies an object's length must make sure the length doesn't go below zero)?

How do I catch these errors (we don't want to see `catch` them in `main()` do we, where the user has control over the handling)?

Or should I just leave all the above aside and switch back to the good old `cout << you entered a wrong value, continuing with the standard value" << endl; val = 1;` ?

*(or is this a thing that depends on what the project is?)*

Comment: _"I'd like to slip in some exception handling"_ You're doing a school project so it's fine, but keep in mind that in most real-life scenario's doing error handling after the code has been written won't cover all the cases and is error-prone.

Comment: @nightcracker the code hasn't really been written yet, so everything is possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does depend somewhat on the project, but for anything but a toy program, you can *rarely* just choose to continue with a default value. Especially when you're writing library code, having a ctor directly display an error message is almost always inappropriate (e.g., if somebody tried to use your code in a Windowed program, `cout` often wouldn't work at all. By throwing an exception, some other part of the program that realizes it's a windowed program can call the appropriate function (e.g., MessageBox on Windows) to display the error message.